# How to configure frequency (Once in a day) to read message from Kafka topic in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to handle failures and writing the message into failure-Q in case if message is failed during db persist due to db is down or any other issue.

We need to re-try the messages from failure-Q once in a day. as we are using properties file to configure the consumer configuration:

```
# KAFKA
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092

## CONSUMER
kafka.topic.consumer.boot: tink_boot.j
kafka.consumer.group-id: tink_boot.j-001
### Kafka from 5000 to 60000
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-commit-interval: 5000
spring.kafka.consumer.client-id: service
### start reading from earliest messages
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset: earliest
```

KafkaListener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.consumer.boot}", groupId = "${kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    public void receiveEvent(Event e){
     log.info("message received: " + e);
    }
```

So how to read the messages from Kafka-Q based on particular time once per day in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) is built to serve messages with streaming, so I would recommend you to run a consumer that is always reading messages from that queue and handles them.
If for some reason you can't handle them right away, spill them to other db which fits to daily batch processing, some examples:

1. Daily folder in the local FileSystem
2. Daily folder in [HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html)
3. Daily rolling index in [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch)
   ...

You can use [KafkaConnect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect) for this, [Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/?utm_medium=sem&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=ch.sem_br.brand_tp.prs_tgt.confluent-brand_mt.xct_rgn.emea_lng.eng_dv.all&utm_term=confluent&creative=&device=c&placement=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyPbzBRDsARIsAFh15JY3mB--jXQCi92z6GykVLPuIJtm1BNL0BSfTgW9A04E7cE2NhEbKb0aAkG_EALw_wcB) have built some [connectors](https://www.confluent.io/hub/?utm_medium=sem&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=ch.sem_br.nonbrand_tp.prs_tgt.kafka_mt.xct_rgn.emea_lng.eng_dv.all&utm_term=kafkaconnect&creative=&device=c&placement=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyPbzBRDsARIsAFh15JYz8exaUAGEcYg_W0x4yohiTvIlyvByfH0EN9VWVHDao2zhkXfJSjwaAiwiEALw_wcB), including [ElasticSearch](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch) and [HDFS](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) from our example.

Comment: is there a way to read messages using intervals in Kafka? @Ofek Hod

Comment: Yes, consumer `session.timeout.ms` can be useful, but other configurations may be relevant, depending on your use case.  I recommend you to read more about Kafka consumer, you can start here: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html